# IncompatibleClassChangeError with Eclipse Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, incompatibility

I am getting the following error when I try to build a project that uses Eclipse Jetty libraries

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: 
  class org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector has interface 
  org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpBuffers as super class
```

The specific Eclipse Jetty libraries I am using are:

```
'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.7.v20120910',
'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.7.v20120910'
```

What is the cause of the error and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a `camel-jetty` dependency, which we replaced with relevant `eclipse-jetty` dependencies. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have something else coming in dependency wise, or something very hinky going on with some classloaders, how are you using this, some sort of embedded usage?